# Getting registered node from Google ILB

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, cloud, internal-load-balancer

We have a scenario where we need to fetch the list of registered nodes on Google ILB(Internal Load Balancer).
Earlier we were using nginx+ where we had REST APIs to get the nodes. Please suggest if there any such way we can get the nodes from google ILB

Answer (score 1):

You can find the instances using the Google Compute Engine API. When using the load balancer, there are several resources involved:

```
                                             +----+
                                         +-->+VM 1|
                                         |   +----+
                                         |
+----------+    +-------+    +--------+  |   +----+
|Forwarding+--->+Backend+--->+Instance+--+-->+VM 2|
|rule      |    |Service|    |Group   |  |   +----+
+----------+    +-------+    +--------+  |
                                         |   +----+
                                         +-->+VM 3|
                                             +----+
```

So what you really want is to list the instances that are in the instance group used by your load balancer. You can do this with the [instanceGroups.listInstances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instanceGroups/listInstances) method.